# ASP.NET core how to have two buttons on the front end go to different functions with the model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to create a second submit button on my screen that will take the value of the model on the front end to delete this user's data. The problem is I don't know how I can have buttons on the same screen point to different functions and then still have the model's data. is there a way I can have two buttons that point to different functions that both pass the same model? if so please let me know how. P.S I'm new to ASP.NET core
My front end code looks like this

```
@if ((currentUser.IsInRole("SuperAdmin")))
{
    *** this button doesnt pass the model***
    <a href="@Url.Action("DeleteUser", "Account")"><input type="button" class="btn-glow primary" value="@_stringLocalizer["DELETE"]" /></a>
}

*** this button passes the model***
<input type="submit" class="btn-glow primary" value="@_stringLocalizer["AccountEditViewSubmitButtonDisplayName"]" id="submit" />
```

The back end looks like this

```
[Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdmin")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteUser(frontEndModel model)***the model is Null
{
    frontEndModel.user = null;
    savechanges();
}

[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,GroupAdmin,SuperAdmin")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(frontEndModel model)
{
  ***uses frontEndModel 
}
```

Comment: I think 1st button is never cliked because it is wrapped around <a>. If these 2 buttons points to different Url, maybe you should create 2 separate <form> tags?

Comment: @apocalypse that doesn't seem to work but thanks

Comment: As mentioned, 2 separate forms might be an option. Also, you can set the `action` of a form with javascript before you `submit()`

Comment: when I have the second form it sends it to the other function (edit) should I not be encasing it within the first form? I don't really want to mess with the styling by pulling it out but if I have to I will. @Crowcoder

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you are asking, but you cannot nest html forms within other forms.

Comment: You need 2 separate <form> tags. Input type should be "submit" for 2 buttons. DeleteUser should be decorated with [HttpPost].